# CUDA: How to check for the right compute capability?

Tags: cuda

CUDA code compiled with a higher compute capability will execute perfectly for a long time on a device with lower compute capability, before silently failing one day in some kernel. I spent half a day chasing an elusive bug only to realize that the Build Rule had `sm_21` while the device (Tesla C2050) was a `2.0`.

Is there any CUDA API code I can add which can self-check if it is running on a device with compatible compute capability? I need to compile and work with devices of many compute capabilities. Is there any other action I can take to ensure such errors do not occur?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the runtime API, [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html) returns two fields `major` and `minor` which return the compute capability any given enumerated CUDA device. You can use that to parse the compute capability of any GPU before establishing a context on it to make sure it is the right architecture for what your code does. `nvcc` can generate a object file containing multiple architectures from a single invocation using the `-gencode` option, for example:

```
nvcc -c -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  \
        -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13  \
        source.cu
```

would produce an output object file with an embedded fatbinary object containing cubin files for GT200 and GF100 cards. The runtime API will automagically handle architecture detection and try loading suitable device code from the fatbinary object without any extra host code.

Comment: Any idea why the binary can detect the device and load suitable version, but does not exit with a meaningful error when there is a single version (that does not match)?

Comment: Too much abstraction, basically. If you do the process "by hand" using the driver API, a meaningful error message is returned if there is no suitable cubin for the target GPU. But a lot of steps all happen implicitly (device selection, context establishment, module loading, code and data retrieval), and if any of those deliberately abstracted processes fail, the runtime returns a generic initialization error. If you need that degree of control, explicitly manage the context yourself with the driver API, then use the context in the runtime API. Interoperability has been supported since CUDA 3.1

Comment: @Ashwin: Accepted an answer two and a half years after it was posted. That must be some sort of record.....

Comment: Haha. Had forgotten to accept I guess. Came across it again today & did the right thing :-D

Comment: nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'sm_13source.cu'
 any more general command?

Answer (score 0):

run device query.
find compute capability for every device in the system.
Then execute code at the desired device with SetDevice();