# Simple adding of two int's in Cuda, result always the same

Tags: cuda

I'm starting my journary to learn Cuda. I am playing with some hello world type cuda code but its not working, and I'm not sure why.

The code is very simple, take two ints and add them on the GPU and return the result, but no matter what I change the numbers to I get the same result(If math worked that way I would have done alot better in the subject than I actually did).

Here's the sample code:

```
// CUDA-C includes
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void add( int a, int b, int *c ) {
    *c = a + b;
}

extern "C"
void runCudaPart();

// Main cuda function

void runCudaPart() {

    int c;
    int *dev_c;

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int) );
    add<<<1,1>>>( 1, 4, dev_c );

    cudaMemcpy( &c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    printf( "1 + 4 = %d\n", c );
    cudaFree( dev_c );

}
```

The output seems a bit off: `1 + 4 = -1065287167`

I'm working on setting up my environment and just wanted to know if there was a problem with the code otherwise its probably my environment.

Update: I tried to add some code to show the error but I don't get an output but the number changes(is it outputing error codes instead of answers? Even if I don't do any work in the kernal other than assign a variable I still get simlair results).

```
// CUDA-C includes
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void add( int a, int b, int *c ) {
    //*c = a + b;
    *c = 5;
}

extern "C"
void runCudaPart();

// Main cuda function

void runCudaPart() {

    int c;
    int *dev_c;

    cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int) );
    if(err != cudaSuccess){
         printf("The error is %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }
    add<<<1,1>>>( 1, 4, dev_c );

    cudaError_t err2 = cudaMemcpy( &c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    if(err2 != cudaSuccess){
         printf("The error is %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }


    printf( "1 + 4 = %d\n", c );
    cudaFree( dev_c );

}
```

Code appears to be fine, maybe its related to my setup. Its been a nightmare to get Cuda installed on OSX lion but I thought it worked as the examples in the SDK seemed to be fine.  The steps I took so far are go to the Nvida website and download the latest mac releases for the driver, toolkit and SDK. I then added `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and 'PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH` I did a deviceQuery and it passed with the following info about my system:

```
[deviceQuery] starting...

/Developer/GPU Computing/C/bin/darwin/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Found 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce 320M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          4.2 / 4.2
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.2
  Total amount of global memory:                 253 MBytes (265027584 bytes)
  ( 6) Multiprocessors x (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:    48 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                950 MHz (0.95 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1064 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(8192), 2D=(65536,32768), 3D=(2048,2048,2048)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(8192) x 512, 2D=(8192,8192) x 512
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 16384
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1024
  Maximum number of threads per block:           512
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    512 x 512 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 1
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            Yes
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   No
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                No
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               No
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           4 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 4.2, CUDA Runtime Version = 4.2, NumDevs = 1, Device = GeForce 320M
[deviceQuery] test results...
PASSED
```

UPDATE: what's really weird is even if I remove all the work in the kernel I stil get a result  for c? I have reinstalled cuda and used make on the examples and all of them pass.

Comment: For starters, both cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy return result codes. It might be educational to print anything that's not cudaSuccess.

Comment: @HenkHolterman no luck..I'm really new to Cuda, so I might be completely wrong but I tried to create an output if there is an error and no message about the error but the numbers changed(even if I put a specific number in the kernel, its not returned.) I updated the code, it seems the kernel isn't even being used.

Comment: I'm typically a believer in "if you see hoof prints, think horses, not zebras", but I can't find anything wrong with this...  what's your set up like?  GPU, CUDA version, compiler, etc.?

Comment: Also, try adding "cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();" immediately after your kernel call.  I just noticed it wasn't there.  I don't remember offhand if cudaMemcpy clears the error flag if it returns successfully or not, so if there was an error in your kernel call, it *may* be getting cleared out.

Comment: @trycatch I updated the question with details about my system,cuda, and the steps I took to install.

Comment: Yeah, you look like you're doing okay there...  I'm not a Mac guy so there could be a Mac-related CUDA issue I don't know about, but it doesn't seem like it would manifest this way.  I would presume you're using GCC..  I'm running out of ideas.  Did cudaGetLastError() immediately after the kernel call return cudaSuccess?  If so, the only thing I can even think of at this point is maybe something is getting optimized out of order and maybe trying -O0 -g in gcc?  I've had an issue with that once before in MFC on Windows, but it's not something I'd suspect here.

Comment: @trycatch I'm using normal gcc 4.2, I am not sure how to use cudagetLasterror message, I'm very green when it comes to C but I tried `printf(cudaGetLastError());` and got a message saying its incapable with const char.  I did all the tests on nvidias site and they report back fine..I'm not sure..

Comment: I copied your code into a CUDA test project and compiled it. It compiled without any issues and worked. (Output: 1 + 4 = 5). Visual Studio 2010, 32 bit project, CUDA 4.1, C.C. 1.1, Windows 7.

Comment: @RogerDahl Thanks so much.  Did you make any modifications at all? or just run it as it is?

Comment: I had to make a tiny change. Removed `extern "C"` to make it link.

Comment: @RogerDahl when I comment out that line I get a error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

That might be a good thing..I can try to fix this problem then..

Comment: @RogerDahl actually I can compile it when I add a main(and return a 0)..

Comment: Have you checked that you're targeting your GPU? If you compile for a higher Compute Capability, the program will fail in some way.

Comment: How do I know my compute capability? I am using CUDA_ARCH = sm_20 to compile?

Comment: actually, I have no idea what happened but it works now. I followed your steps and was able to compile it from the compile line, then I re-ran it again in my IDE that intregates cuda into c++ code and it works!

Comment: The deviceQuery output you listed earlier shows that you have Compute Capability 1.2, so sm20 (C.C 2.0) won't work. Heh... Shouldn't. (Just got your latest comment).

Comment: oh so I should be using sm12?  Thanks man...I'm so happy it works..I felt for a while that Dennis Ritchie's ghost was trying to prevent me from using C and Cuda(joking..well maybe, depends on how bad my code turns out to be)..

Comment: I'm sure Ritchie wouldn't mind. You can supply a semicolon-separated list of architectures and code version for the GPUs you want to target and one of them should be equal or lower to the GPU you want to run on. For example, compute_10,sm_10;compute_13,sm_13;compute_20,sm_20. In the debug build, it's best to keep the list limited to just one target GPU since it helps keep compilation time down.

Comment: ok thats good to know, I'll study the differences because I am developing on my laptop but plan to run on EC2 Telsa fermi cards.  Hey I think your answer helped me(although not sure exactly how because code seems the same). If you want to put a answer I'll accept it since I think your solution was the one that helped..

Comment: I'll add an answer if we can figure out what happened... You mentioned that you needed to add `main()` after removing `extern "C"`. Are you saying that your program ran without `main()` before that..?

Comment: yes it did..So the code I posted above was being called from a C program.  C program had a main and just called runCudaPart(); and it was suppose to run. I reinstalled cuda toolkit,drivers,sdk..then saw your post and copied and pasted the code back into the file, changed it the way you did(comment out the C part), added a main and ran it via nvcc. it worked.  I then ran it again from the C code and it worked. Before when I ran it on its own or C code it gave me the wrong numbers.

Comment: Based on your .pro file configuration of your last question, adjust your device architecture to CUDA_ARCH = sm_13 (not sm_20) as you have a device of compute capability 1.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically there are two problems here:

1. You are not compiling the kernel for the correct architecture (gleaned from comments)
2. Your code contains imperfect error checking which is missing the point when the runtime error is occurring, leading to mysterious and unexplained symptoms.

In the runtime API, most context related actions are performed "lazily". When you launch a kernel for the first time, the runtime API will invoke code to intelligently find a suitable CUBIN image from inside the fat binary image emitted by the toolchain for the target hardware and load it into the context. This can also include JIT recompilation of PTX for a backwards compatible architecture, but not the other way around. So if you had a kernel compiled for a compute capability 1.2 device and you run it on a compute capability 2.0 device, the driver can JIT compile the PTX 1.x code it contains for the newer architecture. But the reverse doesn't work. So in your example, the runtime API will generate an error because it cannot find a usable binary image in the CUDA fatbinary image embedded in the executable. The error message is pretty cryptic, but you will get an error (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6689129/681865) for a bit more information).

If your code contained error checking like this:

```
cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int) );
if(err != cudaSuccess){
     printf("The error is %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
}

add<<<1,1>>>( 1, 4, dev_c );
if (cudaPeekAtLastError() != cudaSuccess) {
    printf("The error is %s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
}

cudaError_t err2 = cudaMemcpy( &c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
if(err2 != cudaSuccess){
     printf("The error is %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
}
```

the extra error checking after the kernel launch should catch the runtime API error generated by the kernel load/launch failure.

Comment: This is probably the best practice for beginners. Check for error at each step while you learn. You should get an error regarding to the device architecture.

Comment: It's also the best practice for pros :) Definitely for debug builds, but I would leave the checks in release builds as well. If the checks are not desired in the release build, use the preprocessor to replace them with stubs.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>


__global__ void Addition(int *a,int *b,int *c)
{

   *c = *a + *b;
}
int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  int *dev_a,*dev_b,*dev_c;
  int size = sizeof(int);

  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size);

  a=5,b=6;

  cudaMemcpy(dev_a, &a,sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  
  cudaMemcpy(dev_b, &b,sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  

  Addition<<< 1,1 >>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c);
  cudaMemcpy(&c, dev_c,size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   cudaFree(&dev_a);
   cudaFree(&dev_b);
   cudaFree(&dev_c);

   printf("%d\n", c);
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```